# Изменения формата файла с html на php

Tags: php, html, css

Столкнулся с непонятной проблемой. После изменения формата с html на php у меня съехала верстка. Поменял на html обратно и все гуд. Скажите,пожалуйста, почему так произошло? Как поменять формат файла на php, но чтобы верстка не съезжала? P.s. Стили в отдельном файле.

Comment: А что значит "изменение формата"? Вы как php-файл запускаете для просмотра?

Comment: Посмотрите исходный код страницы, скорее всего вы что-то на пыхе выводите кроме самой вёрстки.

Comment: @humster_spb , я поставил локальный сервер.

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси , дело в том, что я просто поменял формат файла и все съехало. В самом документе на php не писал.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Проблема решена. Дело в масштабировании сайта.

Comment: А как "масштабирование" связано с изменением файла с html на php?